# CSS Print and @page are not working

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a simple HTML page and on that, I have

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media print {
  @page {
    size: letter portrait;
    padding-left: 5in;
    padding-right: 0.25in;
    padding-top: 1in;
  }
}
```

However, when I print preview in Chrome, it appears completely unaffected. What do I have to do to get Chrome to recognize the `@page` and the media query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need the media query because @page is only for print.

Also, according to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

> You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of
>   the document. Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be
>   ignored.

Maybe using margins instead of padding would work.